# Calling Java methods from C++ using JNI in Cocos2d-x 3.0

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've successfully implemented Android In-app Billing in a Cocos2d-x 2.0 Android app. Now, I'm trying to implement Android In-app Billing in a Cocos2d-x 3.0 Android app. Some of the techniques I used before are not working. I want to understand the cause of the problems.

Specifically, I'm having trouble calling Java methods. The "C++ to Java" JNI part is working. The `IAB` method in AppActivity.java is successfully called from C++:

```
public static void IAB(String s) {
    instance.doIAB(s);
}
```

The trouble starts with `instance`. I'm not a Java programmer, so this is probably ugly. I'm using `instance` to call non-static methods from my static `IAB` method. `instance` is set in `onCreate` after the call to `super.onCreate`:

```
instance = this;
```

Also, I have this declaration inside AppActivity:

```
private static AppActivity instance;
```

This worked in Cocos2d-x 2.0. However, now I'm just receiving a crash on the line:

```
instance.doIAB(s);
```

Ideally, I can run my app in the IDE and see errors in the log. However, Eclipse + Cocos2d-x 3.0 doesn't want to run my app from the IDE. So I'm just using the Cocos2d-x 3.0 command line way of running the Android app. This is limiting my understanding of the crash.

**How can I understand and fix this issue?**

Comment: Do you check for `instance` being `null` before you make the call to `doIAB`?  Just saying that you set instance to `this` doesn't tell us the real flow of your program.

Comment: Just added that check. Crash is still there.

Comment: If the crash is within the Java code, you would get a call stack.  So is the crash within Java, or is it within your C++ code?  If it's in the C++ code, you get those "HotSpot JVM" error log generated.  Do you see any?

Comment: Looking at call stack with `adb logcat` now.

Comment: Does `AppActivity` have the `doIAB` method? It may be a stupid question but you didn't say anything about any inheritance or about `doIAB` implementation.

Comment: @Losiowaty yes that method is there. I forget what exactly was causing the crash. Using logcat helped figure it out.